# Is there a way to check for manifest permission from code?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

How do I check for a specific permission in the manifest.xml from code? I want to throw some exception if some permissions that are necessay for my application are missing.

**For example**, `FINE_LOCATION` and `COARSE_LOCATION` I know that android will also throw an exception on the launch of the specific activiy that is using GPS, but I need to check the manifest  and throw an exception at the launch of the application itself. This holds not only for location access, but also for other permissions.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can check whether the permission is granted or not for specific permission by using **PackageManager**. For example

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    if (pm.checkPermission(permission.FINE_LOCATION, getPackageName()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: The above solution will not work on Android 6.0 if you set targetSdkVersion to 23

Answer (score 12):

You can read the available `<uses-permission>` tags at runtime using the following. Tested on older Android versions AND Android 6 and 7

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
try
{
    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    String[] requestedPermissions = null;
    if (packageInfo != null) {
        requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
    }

    if (requestedPermissions != null && requestedPermissions.length > 0)
    {
        List<String> requestedPermissionsList = Arrays.asList(requestedPermissions);
        ArrayList<String> requestedPermissionsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        requestedPermissionsArrayList.addAll(requestedPermissionsList);

        Log.i(ExConsts.TAG, ""+requestedPermissionsArrayList);
    }
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```